# ElasticSearch PV stayed in Released status when uninstalling chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pvc

When uninstalling a helm chart PVs are gone to status Retain-Released and PVCs are deleted.
Also, when i try again to install helm chart it creates new dummy PVs and bounds them with PVCs.

I use this command to manual change Released status of PV to Available again:
kubectl patch pv <pv_name> --type json -p '[{"op": "remove", "path": "/spec/claimRef/uid"}]'

Can this be done by changing yaml file and without this using the above command?

Or is there a way to prevent deleting specific PVCs when uninstalling a helm chart in order to stay in status bound?

Answer (score 1):

the behaviour of deleting PVs (or not) when releasing PVCs depends on the configuration of the `reclaimPolicy` of your storage class.

if your storage class is configured to `reclaimPolicy: Retain`, the PVs won't be deleted if the PVCs are.

if your storage class is configured with `reclaimPolicy: Delete`, the PVs will be deleted if the PVCs are.

see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#reclaim-policy for more information. :)

Comment: My concern is not if PVs will be deleted but why PVs after deleting PVCs are in status retain-released and not retain-available in order to use them again. Also, is there a way to prevent deleting specific PVCs when uninstalling a helm chart in order to stay in status bound? i.e.     annotations: helm.sh/resource-policy: keep

Comment: re-using pv's that were bound to a pvc before is deprecated, see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#reclaiming and the sections below.

when you are the developer of the chart, you can add the mentioned helm annotation and `helm uninstall` won't delete it, but the resource will get orphaned (unmanaged by helm). if  the chart does not give you the option to add this annotation where you would like to, you can fork the chart, change it on your behalf and add the annotation this way. creating a PR to enhance this chart would work too. :)